# ERROR: invalid XML content, when Select unnest(xpath(... on a text column

Tags: postgresql, xml

I have a text column named big_xml in my table which has the following value:

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
<dpid:DpidDatabase xmlns:dpid=http://ddex.net/xml/dpid/11 xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xsi:schemaLocation=http://ddex.net/xml/dpid/11 http://ddex.net/xml/dpid/11/dpid.xsd>
 <DpidOwner SequenceNumber=1>
  <DPID>PADPIDA2006111001O</DPID>
  <CompanyName>234AG</CompanyName>
  <Address>Riedtlistrasse 23, Zürich, 8006, CH</Address>
 </DpidOwner>
 <DpidOwner SequenceNumber=2>
  <DPID>PADPIDA2007011501Q</DPID>
  <CompanyName>OpenIMP</CompanyName>
  <Address>8-10 Rhoda Street, London, E2 7EF, UK</Address>
 </DpidOwner>
 <DpidOwner SequenceNumber=3>
  <DPID>PADPIDA2007040501K</DPID>
  <CompanyName>The Harry Fox Agency</CompanyName>
  <Address>711 Third Avenue, 8th Floor, New York, 10017, USA</Address>
 </DpidOwner>
</dpid:DpidDatabase>
```

Execute query:

```
SELECT 
  unnest((xpath('/dpid:DpidDatabase/DpidOwner',  table1.big_xml::xml,ARRAY[ARRAY['dpid', 'http://ddex.net/xml/dpid/11']]))) AS SequenceNumber   
  ,unnest((xpath('/dpid:DpidDatabase/DpidOwner/DPID',  table1.big_xml::xml,ARRAY[ARRAY['dpid', 'http://ddex.net/xml/dpid/11']]))) AS DPID
  ,unnest((xpath('/dpid:DpidDatabase/DpidOwner/CompanyName',  table1.big_xml::xml,ARRAY[ARRAY['dpid', 'http://ddex.net/xml/dpid/11']]))) AS CompanyName 
  ,unnest((xpath('/dpid:DpidDatabase/DpidOwner/Address',  table1.big_xml::xml,ARRAY[ARRAY['dpid', 'http://ddex.net/xml/dpid/11']]))) AS Address
FROM table1_20190828
```

Error displayed:

```
ERROR: invalid XML content
 Detail: line 1: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
        ^
1 statement failed.
```

Comment: The column contains invalid XML see McNets answer for details. This is one reason such a column should be defined with the type `xml` which will prevent inserting invalid XML in the first place. Queries like that (once the XML is valid) are also easier to do using `xmltable()`

Answer (score 1):

Basically **double-quote all attribute values**.

You can read about it in [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_attributes.htm).

I used an on-line [xml validator](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/) and this is the result:

> The value following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string.

Change:

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
```

by

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

> Open quote is expected for attribute "xmlns:dpid" associated with an element type "dpid:DpidDatabase".

Change:

```
<dpid:DpidDatabase xmlns:dpid=http://ddex.net/xml/dpid/11 xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xsi:schemaLocation=http://ddex.net/xml/dpid/11 http://ddex.net/xml/dpid/11/dpid.xsd>
```

by

```
<dpid:DpidDatabase xmlns:dpid="http://ddex.net/xml/dpid/11" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ddex.net/xml/dpid/11 http://ddex.net/xml/dpid/11/dpid.xsd">
```

> Open quote is expected for attribute "SequenceNumber" associated with an element type "DpidOwner".

Change all occurrences of:

```
<DpidOwner SequenceNumber=XX>
```

by double quoting SequenceNumber values

```
<DpidOwner SequenceNumber="1">
```

You can check the result *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=db2758b6955b8cec100a05860deb9541)*

> ```
> sequencenumber                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | dpid                            | companyname                                     | address                                                                                                                           
> :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :------------------------------ | :---------------------------------------------- | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> <DpidOwner SequenceNumber="1"><br>  <DPID>PADPIDA2006111001O</DPID><br>  <CompanyName>234AG</CompanyName><br>  <Address>Riedtlistrasse 23, ZÃƒ????????Ãƒ???????Ãƒ??????Ãƒ?????Ãƒ????Ãƒ???Ãƒ??Ãƒ?Ã‚Â¼rich, 8006, CH</Address><br> </DpidOwner> | <DPID>PADPIDA2006111001O</DPID> | <CompanyName>234AG</CompanyName>                | <Address>Riedtlistrasse 23, ZÃƒ????????Ãƒ???????Ãƒ??????Ãƒ?????Ãƒ????Ãƒ???Ãƒ??Ãƒ?Ã‚Â¼rich, 8006, CH</Address>
> <DpidOwner SequenceNumber="2"><br>  <DPID>PADPIDA2007011501Q</DPID><br>  <CompanyName>OpenIMP</CompanyName><br>  <Address>8-10 Rhoda Street, London, E2 7EF, UK</Address><br> </DpidOwner>                                                                         | <DPID>PADPIDA2007011501Q</DPID> | <CompanyName>OpenIMP</CompanyName>              | <Address>8-10 Rhoda Street, London, E2 7EF, UK</Address>                                                                          
> <DpidOwner SequenceNumber="3"><br>  <DPID>PADPIDA2007040501K</DPID><br>  <CompanyName>The Harry Fox Agency</CompanyName><br>  <Address>711 Third Avenue, 8th Floor, New York, 10017, USA</Address><br> </DpidOwner>                                                | <DPID>PADPIDA2007040501K</DPID> | <CompanyName>The Harry Fox Agency</CompanyName> | <Address>711 Third Avenue, 8th Floor, New York, 10017, USA</Address>
> ```